# How are the different sleep modes used for esp8266?

Tags: wifi

I am currently trying to power my esp8266 with a battery, but I want to decrease the power consumption (current mostly). I understand there are different sleep modes, but I do not understand what can I use for each sleep mode. I want to know what functions are still enabled during each sleep mode.

Example: Can I use ADC pins in modem sleep?

My biggest question:
I am sending beacon frames to my phone, I want to know if I can use one of these sleep modes while sending my beacons at the same time? Do I need my CPU or do I need my Clock to send frames?